# Seed() not fully updating the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm giving a go through some tutorials ([here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)) on ASP.NET MVC, and decided to try a few things on my own. Now, I've got three tables, `Resume`, `Descriptions`, `SubDescriptions`. Here's the code for the three:

```
public class Resume
{
    public Resume()
    {
        Descriptions = new List<Description>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ResumeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Employer { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class Description
{
    public Description()
    {
        SubDescriptions = new List<SubDescription>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int DescriptionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Resume")]
    public int ResumeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public virtual Resume Resume { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubDescription> SubDescriptions { get; set; }
}

public class SubDescription
{
    [Key]
    public int SubDescriptionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Description")]
    public int DescriptionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Sub { get; set; }

    public virtual Description Description { get; set; }
}
```

And my `Seed()` is as follows:

```
protected override void Seed(ResumeDBContext context)
{
    context.Resumes.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Employer,
                                new Resume
                                    {
                                        Employer = "Employer Test",
                                        StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-3-26"),
                                        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-10-24"),
                                        Location = "Houston, TX",
                                        Descriptions = { new Description 
                                                             { Desc = "DescTest",
                                                               SubDescriptions = {new SubDescription {Sub = "SubTest"},
                                                                                  new SubDescription {Sub = "SubTest2"},
                                                                                  new SubDescription {Sub = "SubTest3"}}
                                                             },
                                                         new Description { Desc = "DescTest2" }}
                                    }
                                 );
}
```

Now, whenever I run `update-database` from my Package Manager Console, it says it's running `Seed()`. However, upon querying the database, my `SubDescriptions` table is still empty. Everything else populates as expected. I don't receive any errors, or anything of the sort. Am I missing something silly in my associations?

The `Resume` table is populated properly from the `Seed()`, and the `Descriptions` table is populated as well, with the appropriate association to the `Resume` table. Yet, following the same example to try to populate `SubDescriptions`, the table is just flat out empty. The associations and navigation properties appear to be set correctly, but as I'm new to this, I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Are you sure that the Descriptions table gets populated?

Comment: @BorisB. Yes. When I query the table, the default info from `Seed()` is there. It's also there when I actually run the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer quite by accident. I dropped and recreated the database, and when it ran `Seed()` again, it populated all my tables as it should. Initially, I was making changes to the `Seed()` and updating, hoping that they'd be applied. But since the data already existed in the tables, it wasn't populating.